# Database results to two level menu

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

This is result I get from database (mysql). Now I would like to get menu with structure like

```
department title1
- project1
- project2
department title2
- project3
- project4
....
```

This are my results

```
project title   |   department title    | department_id 
 project1       |   department1         |   9
 project2       |   department2         |   2
 project3       |   department3         |   1
 project11      |   department1         |   9
 project23      |   department2         |   2
 project24      |   department3         |   1
 project15      |   department1         |   9
 project26      |   department2         |   2
 project21      |   department4         |   4
```

I'm using laravel 4.2.(and this will be in blade syntax) if this is any help.

Here's what I tried so far:
In my controller

```
//projects is above results from db query builder
 foreach($projects as $project)
         {
            if($project->department_id != "")
            {
              $department = array(
               "id" => $project->department_id,
               "title" => $project->department_title, 
              );
              $departments_projects[] = array_push($departments_projects,$department);
            }
         }
```

And then in my view (where I'm build the menu) I have this code

```
 <ul class="sub-menu">
            @foreach($departments as $department)
            <li class="">
              <a href="javascript:;">
                {{ $department['title'] }} <i class="icon-arrow"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="sub-menu">
                @foreach($projects as $project)
                  @if($project->department_id == $department['id'] && $project->title != "")
                    <li>
                      <a href="{{ route('department.project.show',array($project->department_id,$project->id)) }}">
                        {{ $project->title }}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  @endif
                @endforeach

              </ul>
            </li>
            @endforeach
          </ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question with code I've got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would be better to solve this in MySQL end, but if you want to do it after you retrieve the result, you can try something along these lines:

The solution works under the premise that you have a result in the following structure:

```
$projects = [
    [
        'project_title' => 'project2',
        'department_title' => 'department2',
        'department_id' => 2
    ],
    [
        'project_title' => 'project1',
        'department_title' => 'department1',
        'department_id' => 9
    ],
    [
        'project_title' => 'project3',
        'department_title' => 'department3',
        'department_id' => 1
    ],
    [
        'project_title' => 'project11',
        'department_title' => 'department1',
        'department_id' => 9
    ],
    [
        'project_title' => 'project13',
        'department_title' => 'department2',
        'department_id' => 2
    ],
];
```

We initially get a unique array of department titles and we sort it alphabetically. Then, we create a `$departments` array which has the department titles as keys and includes the structure that we'll use.

Then, we iterate through the `$projects` array and we fill the details in the appropriate fields of the `$departments` array.

Finally, we sort the projects alphabetically as well.

```
$department_names = array_unique(array_column($projects, 'department_title'));
sort($department_names);

$departments = array_fill_keys($department_names, [
    'id' => null,
    'projects' => []
]);

foreach($projects as $project) {
    $departments[$project['department_title']]['id'] = $project['department_id'];
    $departments[$project['department_title']]['projects'][] = $project['project_title'];
}

foreach($departments as $key => $department) {
    sort($departments[$key]['projects']);
}

var_dump($departments);
```

That will produce:

```
array(3) {
  ["department1"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(9)
    ["projects"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "project1"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "project11"
    }
  }
  ["department2"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["projects"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "project13"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "project2"
    }
  }
  ["department3"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["projects"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "project3"
    }
  }
}
```

You can use the `$departments` array to produce something similar to the following:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($departments as $key => $department) { ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $key; ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($department['projects'] as $project) { ?>
            <li><?php echo $project; ?></li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

An alternative is to use the department IDs as keys and then sort the array alphabetically based on the title value.

```
$department_ids = array_unique(array_column($projects, 'department_id'));

$departments = array_fill_keys($department_ids, [
    'title' => null,
    'projects' => []
]);

foreach($projects as $project) {
    $departments[$project['department_id']]['title'] = $project['department_title'];
    $departments[$project['department_id']]['projects'][] = $project['project_title'];
}

foreach($departments as $key => $department) {
    sort($departments[$key]['projects']);
}

uasort($departments, function ($x, $y) {
    return strcasecmp($x['title'], $y['title']);
});

var_dump($departments);
```

That will produce:

```
array(3) {
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(11) "department1"
    ["projects"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "project1"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "project11"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(11) "department2"
    ["projects"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "project13"
      [1]=>
      string(8) "project2"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(11) "department3"
    ["projects"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(8) "project3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't get department_id and project_id so that I can produce url . 
<a href="{{ route('department.project.show',array($project->department_id,$project->id)) }}">

Comment: @SuperManSL You're welcome. I didn't give you plug-and-play code, it it not even laravel-specific; you'll have to adapt it to your needs.

Project ID was not mentioned in the result example you provided, but you can easily modify the code and add it.

As for department_id, in the first example, you can retrieve it as $department['id'] while you are iterating through the $departments array. In the second one, if you iterate in the same manner, it will be the $key variable.